# Firebase & Zapier for Email/SMS

Tags: firebase, zapier

We are currently developing an application using firebase, and considering to use Zapier's service to send email/sms.

We are trying to do something like here [SMS Example](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/10/sms-notifications-angularjs-firebase-twilio.html)

"New item in Queue", is this option no longer available as firebase trigger? If not, how can we reference dynamic path as trigger path?

Comment: We got some feedback from Zapier support team. 

Due to some technical issues, Zapier had to remove this trigger. New API is currently under development which will allow to reintroduce a trigger along those lines in the future. until then any other workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

I used google app engine to create a simple email and SMS sending service. Then the firebase app call the app engine service to send mails. Note that you need to allow cros domain response on the app engine service, and connect it to your domain. This is a free an simple solution.